# Access to json array in php

Tags: php, json

I have this json object and i need to iterate each text and value keys, please can somebody help me on this?

I've tried in too many ways but no success next to the json is my last try

Thanks in advance

```
[
    {
        "term": [
            {
                "text": "36",
                "value": "36"
            },
            {
                "text": "48",
                "value": "48"
            },
            {
                "text": "60",
                "value": "60"
            },
            {
                "text": "72",
                "value": "72"
            },
            {
                "text": "84",
                "value": "84"
            },
            {
                "text": "96",
                "value": "96"
            },
            {
                "text": "120",
                "value": "120"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying this way but no success

```
foreach($Terms['term'] as $key=>$val){ 
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you create the `$Terms` array?

Comment: You have an array wrapping an object wrapping an array...

Comment: [code]
$optionsXML = simplexml_load_file("js/SelectParams.xml");
$Terms = $optionsXML->xpath("//ProductBase[@Id=".$ProductData->ProductBaseId."]/terms");

$Terms = json_encode($Terms);
[/code]

Comment: @martinezjc: `[code]` tags don't work in comments (or anywhere on SO). Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22723129/edit) the original question to add more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decode JSON into array (or object), only then you can access it's elements.

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
// according to your data, you have an array inside object, which is inside another array.
foreach ($data[0]['term'] as $key => $value) {
}
```

Comment: I made this

    json_decode($Terms, true);

Now im getting this error

    Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Forget about it i remove the extra zero index and now is working like a charm, thanks!!!!